# Relative Layout inside Card View is not filling the parent even after giving match_parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a cardView layout as below. I have used Stetho to inspect layout in chrome.  I could see that Linear Layout is filling the screen width. However, relative Layout  is not filling the parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_show_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="100dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_layout_show_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_view_show_card"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </FrameLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: not filling height or width ?

Comment: You have closed `LinearLayout` at first in XML design. `linearlayout` is parent to `relativelayout`

Comment: I am sorry. That was editing issue.  @ Hemath, It is not filling width

Comment: your relative layout and linear layout are useless delete them

Comment: I think you don't need the LinearLayout here. Give RelativeLayout height match parent.

Answer (score 0):

Relative layout fills the parent. Try applying different for the layouts to prove it. Something like this...

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#3367bb"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_layout_show_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">



                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_view_show_card"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </FrameLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

You will see that the complete layout becomes black, that means it covers the parent.
If you remove background color of relative layout, you will get to see blue color of linear layout.
If the issue is something else, please ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add this inside of your CardView:
`app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"`